# Postgres 11 Stored Procedure not returning results

Tags: stored-procedures, postgresql-11

In Postgres 11, are stored procedures not intended to return result sets?  Because when we run the following, it says it ran successfully but no results are returned.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test()
LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
  SELECT * from aTable;
$$;

call test();
```

Comment: If you want to return a result, use a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Postgresql procedures can return at most a single value:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test (INOUT x int)
LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
    SELECT x;
$$;

# call test (1);
 x
---
 1
(1 row)
```

Postgresql **functions** are much more flexible:

```
create or replace function test()
RETURNS setof atable
language sql
as $$
select * from atable;
$$;
```

The advantage of procedures is that they can control transactions.  If you don't need that, you are likely better off with a function.