# Stored Procedure - return result set - Postgres 11

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, postgresql-11

Is it possible to return some result set from a Postgres 11 stored procedure?

I think it's not but I want to be sure.

I see another person asked here but got no replies.

[Postgres 11 Stored Procedure not returning results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53787546/postgres-11-stored-procedure-not-returning-results)

Please point me to some authoritative reference if possible.

Comment: If you want to draw attention to a previously-asked question, you can [set a bounty on that question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Comment: If you want to return something you should use a function.